# RecyclerView keeps changing sizes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to build a atractive recyclerview but the size keeps changing and I don't know why
If I scroll up/down it changes
Here is an exemple of taking a screenshot then scrolling down then up:

[First screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTh2s.jpg)

[Second screenshot after scrolling down/up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JURVT.jpg)

Adapter:

pastebin.com/jYRXJSMe

pastebin.com/m0JMrpwr

```
    /* Code for the recycler */
    mRecycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.activity_movies_recycler);
    mRecycler.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerInsetsDecoration(this));
    mRecycler.addOnScrollListener(recyclerScrollListener);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRecycler.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mRecycler.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

This is the code for the RecyclerInsetsDecoration

```
public class RecyclerInsetsDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int mInsets;

    public RecyclerInsetsDecoration(Context context) {
        mInsets = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.insets);
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        //We can supply forced insets for each item view here in the Rect
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.set(mInsets, mInsets, mInsets, mInsets);
    }
}
```

Recycler layouts:
pastebin.com/37x9m9XN

Comment: Can you post your code please, especially adapter and xml

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz Sorry, its now updated